# Organizing data output with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table with data:

```
t1 (results):    card_id     group_id    project_id    user_id
```

The tables that contain actual labels are:

```
t2 (groups):    id    project_id    label

t3 (cards):     id    project_id    label
```

There could be multiple entries by different users.

I need help with writing a query to display the results in a table format with totals counts corresponding card/group. Here's my start but I'm not sure that I'm on the right track...

```
SELECT COUNT(card_id) AS cTotal, COUNT(group_id) AS gTotal
WHERE project_id = $projID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, it seems that all you need to do is group by card_id and group_id for the given project_id and pull out the count for each group

```
SELECT card_id, group_id, COUNT(user_id) FROM mytable 
WHERE project_id = 001
GROUP BY (card_id, group_id);
```

**EDIT:**

Taking into account the card and group tables involves some joins, but the query is fundamentally the same. Still grouping by card and group, and constraining by project id

```
SELECT c.label, g.label, COUNT(t1.user_id) FROM mytable t1 
JOIN groups g ON t1.group_id=g.id 
JOIN cards c ON t1.card_is=c.id 
WHERE t1.project_id = 001 
GROUP BY (c.card_id, g.group_id) 
ORDER BY (c.card_id, g.group_id);
```

I don't think you can get a table as you want with just SQL. You'll have to render the table in code by iterating over the results. How you do that depends on what language/platform you are using.

Comment: My bad, my original post omitted labels of the groups and cards. I updated my post.

Comment: @santa: LEFT JOIN is not necessary unless you want to include rows for card_id's that no longer exist in the cards table, or columns for group_id's that no longer exist in the groups table. If you wish to ignore cards that have been removed from the cards table, you don't need a LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1):

if you know for a fixed fact that there are nine groups, then just include those groups in subqueries - similar to this:

```
select cTotal, g1.gTotal as Group1, g2.gTotal as Group2... etc
from
( SELECT COUNT(card_id) AS cTotal
, COUNT(group_id) AS gTotal
WHERE project_id = $projID
AND group_id = 1 ) g1
, ( SELECT COUNT(card_id) AS cTotal
, COUNT(group_id) AS gTotal
WHERE project_id = $projID
AND group_id = 2 ) g2
etc.
```

Comment: I don't know how many groups there might be -- it depends on a project.